# Issue with WSO2 user management

Tags: wso2, saml, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

Using WSO2 Identity Server with SAML 2.0.

I have multiple application for that I have implemented SSO through SAML and every thing is working fine.

**Problem** I want to restrict some user to access of some application.

Let's say, there is 2 application and 3 users so User1 should access only App1 but not App2.

Comment: as already answered the best practice is let the SP to authorize the user access based on the claims. However since wso2is 5.3.0 there is a way to authorize user authentication based on roles https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/60493846

Answer (score 0):

There's various ways to achieve this. The application controlled approach is to provide a user role to the relying party by allowing roles to be exposed as part of the SAML assertion in the service provider. The server-based approach is to create XACML policies within the server and then enabling Authorization in the service provider. The WSO2 training materials describe how this is done in the WSO IS advanced training materials available here:

https://github.com/wso2/WSO2-Training/releases/tag/IS530AA